# Setting cookies in Laravel Octane / Swoole

Tags: php, cookies, swoole, laravel-octane

I'm attempting to set cookies on Laravel Octane, however the cookies appear to be not defined on the given index.

```
setcookie(self::JWT_TOKEN_COOKIE, $token_details['access_token'], [
         'httponly' => true,
         'expires' => time() + $token_details['expires_in'],
         'path' => '/'
]);

die($_COOKIE[self::JWT_TOKEN_COOKIE]);
```

When attempting to print the Cookie, I get an error telling me it hasnt been set.

> Undefined array key "JWT_TOKEN"

Is there something wrong in the way I'm setting cookies in Laravel Octane? Is there a new class I should be using to use these as the application is now fully held in RAM/loaded once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setcookie` function add the `Set-Cookie` header

Superglobal array `$_COOKIE` reads from the `Cookie` header

Remove the `die` function and reload the page, cookie will appear

Example

```php
<?php

setcookie('a', 'b', ['httponly' => true, 'expires' => time() + 30, 'path' => '/']);

print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Request to the script with saving cookies to tmp file

```
curl http://localhost:8000/ -c /tmp/cookies.txt --verbose
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<---------- setcookie ---------->
< Set-Cookie: a=b; expires=Sun, 27-Mar-2022 23:50:36 GMT; Max-Age=30; path=/; HttpOnly
< 
<---------- print_r ---------->
Array 
(
)
* Closing connection 0
```

Request to the script with saved cookies

```
curl http://localhost:8000/ -b /tmp/cookies.txt --verbose
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
<---------- readed from /tmp/cookies.txt ---------->
> Cookie: a=b
> 
<---------- setcookie ---------->
* Replaced cookie a="b" for domain localhost, path /, expire 1648425170
< Set-Cookie: a=b; expires=Sun, 27-Mar-2022 23:52:51 GMT; Max-Age=30; path=/; HttpOnly
< 
<---------- print_r ---------->
Array
(
    [a] => b
)
* Closing connection 0
```

#### Use laravel response object to send the cookie

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses